# how to use of sed command to search string with "/" character in it and replace with some other string?

Tags: sed

I have run the command:

```
sed 's/http:\/\//www/' filename
```

In output,this command didn't replace "http://" with "www" why?

and how to change delimiter in `sed` command?

Comment: your command seems alright..working for me.. did you mean it has not replaced all occurrences of `http://` ? your command will only replace the first one of the line..

Comment: yup. it was not in first line so what should i do to replace from whole file?

Answer (score 1):

Your original command is alright provided you want to substitute only the first occurrence of `http://` of the line with `www`:

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo http:// bar http:// spam
egg http:// test http://

$ sed 's/http:\/\//www/' file.txt 
foo www bar http:// spam
egg www test http://
```

Now, as you want to replace all occurrences of `http://` with `www`, just add the modifier `g` at the end:

```
$ sed 's/http:\/\//www/g' file.txt 
foo www bar www spam
egg www test www
```

If you want to set a character other than `/` as the delimiter, you can choose a character that has no special meaning to `sed` and easier to implement in the test case e.g. underscore (`_`)will be good choice in this case:

```
$ sed 's_http://_www_g' file.txt 
foo www bar www spam
egg www test www
```

If you want to modify the original file with the changed contents, you need `-i` option to edit the file in place:

```
$ sed -i 's_http://_www_g' file.txt
```

If you want to take a backup of original file at the same time:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's_http://_www_g' file.txt
```

After this operation, the original file will be kept as `file.txt.bak` and the modified file as `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

That won't actually replace the contents of the existing file, you will need to redirect the output to a file.

```
sed 's/http:\/\//www/' filename > filename.new
```

or by using the -i option,

```
sed -i.bak 's/http:\/\//www/' filename
```

This will make a copy with .bak extension of the file, then overwrite the original with the output of the `sed` command.

Also That will also leave you without a `.` between the domain, might wanna drop a `.` after www.

EDIT:
As for the delimiter question, please check this. Examples are given,

From: [using-different-delimiters-in-sed](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/)

Basically, sed takes whatever follows the "s" as the separator.

`sed 's_/a/b/c/_/d/e/f/_'`

In this example `_` is the delimeter.

Comment: yes i want to change escape character as delimiter with some other special character.how?

Comment: Check my edit + link. It has examples.